How to create conditional assignment in initialValues of Formik
I have initialValues in Formik but I want to assign values in accordance with another field.
I have this code:
const initialValues: MyValues = {
    fieldType: fieldType.FIELDA,
    fieldInformation: '',
    fieldB: '', 
    dateRange: {
      from: lastWeek,
      to: today,
    },
  };

I want something like:
const initialValues: MyValues = {
    fieldType: fieldType.FIELDA,
    fieldInformation: '',
    fieldB: fieldType === fieldType.FieldA ? 'all' : '', 
    dateRange: {
      from: lastWeek,
      to: today,
    },
  };

So fieldB depends on the value of fieldType. How can I achieve that? The problem is that fieldType is a radioButton and I want to initialize with '' if fieldType.FIELDB is chosen.
Edit: This also did not help. Syntax was correct.
fieldB: { fieldType: fieldType.FIELDA } ? 'all : '',


I'm not familiar with Formik, but is there an issue using a ternary for this assignment? What errors do you receive? Other than the check for fieldType against fieldType.FieldA seemingly never being true (as you're comparing an entire object to one of its properties)

IDE does not recognize fieldType  here in fieldB: fieldType === fieldType.FieldA ? 'all' : '',

Is that just a linting issue? What happens when you actually execute the code? If it is a legitimate problem, where is fieldType defined, and what is its value.

No it does not build at all. It does not recognize the field.

You can use watch method which is returned from the useForm hook. Or you can create a watcher for it using a hook called useWatch and then update the values conditionally.
useWatch reference: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/usewatch
watch reference: https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/watch
If there was any questions, I would be happy to help.
